# PHP: Can we build a web application to send email from localhost, like ThunderBirds, OutLook.?

Tags: php, web-services, email

I don't know whether or not it's a good question :(
But my intention is to know if it is possible to to build an email client application like Thunderbird or OutLook . And can we able to configure/create a Web Application in PHP?

Please let me know your thoughts!
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I understand the question, but here a couple of notes :

- if you want to create a web application, of course you can use PHP : it's been created for that task, and does it well

  - if you want to develop a webmail (ie, a web application to send/receive mail), it'll mean **lots** of work...
  - maybe taking a look at some existing webmails might be wiser ?
  - About that, you might be interested by [my answer to the question How do you build a web based email client using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092723/1190735#1190735)
- if you want to create a desktop application, this is possible too ;-)

  - take a look at [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) *(GTK is the graphic toolkit used for Gnome and/or the Gimp, for instance)*, about that ; here are a couple links :
  - [Desktop Application Development with PHP-GTK](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/desktop-application-development-with-php-gtk-8-03-13/page1.html)
  - [Beginning PHP-GTK: Creating a Simple Interface](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/16770-beginning-php-gtk-creating-simple-interface-tutorial.html)
  - [Beginning PHP-GTK: Signals](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/18774-beginning-php-gtk-signals.html)

Answer (score 1):

Uh, sure, but why would you do so? Thunderbird is free and open-source. You could just use that. Unless you've a compelling reason to develop an entirely new e-mail client, it's better not to reinvent the wheel.

Plenty of open-source webmail clients already exist, too. [RoundCube](http://roundcube.net/) is one of the prettiest.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is usually used as a server-side scripting language to build web applications. It does have the functionality that you need to be able [to send email messages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) from a properly configured server.

Answer (score 0):

The mail should definitely be sent from the server not the local machine, but its perfectly ok to create a webmail system. Also you can retrieve incoming mails from your mail server. Actually there are webmail clients on the market that you can use. I personally like [Squirrel Mail](http://squirrelmail.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in your case that you look at using PHP as core backend and (x)html+javascript+ajax for frontend and front-to-backend communications.

Ajax is very good for dynamic pages where you do not want page reloads etc.
You could have a local smtp server to send the email, but most internet providers would not allow this. If the later is the case you need to use the internet providers smtp, alternatively allow the configuration of smtp within the user interface.

PHP has builtin classes to send mail which makes this process easy in either case.
Receiving mail and parsing them correctly is just a matter of understanding the correct protocols. (pop3 / exchange and so on).

I know this wasn't a straightforward answer, but I hope it gave at least some insight.