# create an email drop box with php, javascript etc

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery

I am in the midst of creating an online contact management tool for users to manage contacts and clients. I am trying to develop a solution where the user will add a `BCC` or `CC` in any email client like this:

```
1234@myappdomain.12345.com
```

and my app will grab the recipients `to` address information email, name, etc and my backend script will grab the data, look to see if this exist and if not add this into the database.

Where I am challenged is how to get the data from an email to php or java... Any thoughts?

Comment: *PHP or Java*? And what do you mean by "in any email client"?

Comment: I believe he's asking how can you 'fetch' emails with php/java.

Comment: Any email client= gmail, outlook, hotmail.

Comment: Nevermind, I finally put the first part of the question together with the second.

Comment: You could setup that address to go to a real inbox and then use [IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) to pull the emails and get the data from them.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1190735/451969 SquirrelMail might be perfect for such an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this which you can use to parse the received email headers and grab the recipient information as well as attachments, etc:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

That also links to some other articles on how to actually 'receive' emails with php.

Comment: I have found a solution and built the code to help with this process. My application will allow you send attachments to either a project, person or company. The script will parse the attachments drop them in the appropiate folder, add to the database and then delete the email. If anyone interested in the code, just let me know.

Comment: Glad you got it going! This sounds like a very useful script, have you put it up on GitHub? I'm keen to have a look.